# Enemy AI lender game engine

Tags: game-engine

Is it possible to have an enemy in game that follows u using a 3d navmesh around the sphere? Or have an enemy AI that doesn't use a navemesh at all and maybe flys around the player?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an always sensor logic brick on the enemy character with a steering actuator for every direction the it will go. You might have to play around with this but that’s what makes BGE fun. Let me know if it works.